# "educational and communication opportunities"

Tags: word-usage

Is it fine to say

The Internet provides many educational and communication opportunities to us.

My concern is that "communication" is a noun, and "educational" is an adjective.  Should I use some adjective form of "communication", and what is that?

What would you say instead, if you have a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you're stuck trying to find a word, and nothing's coming to mind, you can always try rewriting the sentence:

> The Internet provides us with many opportunities for both education and communication.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your sentence,

> The Internet provides many educational and communication opportunities to us.

is fine, although it is possible to use *for us* instead, and it might sound a little better to rephrase it as *The Internet provides us with ..."* (as suggested in godel9's answer).

However, I also think that you can use either *"education and communication opportunities"* or *"educational and communication opportunities"*. I couldn't tell why I thought that way at first, until a few moments ago. Here is what I think,

> *education and communication opportunities* (the opportunities for the society as a whole)
>   *educational and communication opportunities* (the opportunities for people in the society)

---

Having said that, I personally prefer simple words. Here is how I might rephrase the sentence:

> The Internet provides us with many opportunities for learning, networking, and collaboration.

If this is the opening sentence, I might rephrase it to put even more emphasis on the opportunities that the Internet brings to us, not just provides us with:

> The Internet opens up many opportunities for learning, networking, and collaboration.

Comment: PS. Everyone is invited to discuss the difference of *education and communication opportunities* vs. *educational and communication opportunities*. What I wrote is the best I can think of, but I don't know if that is the norm.